# How to use RingtonePreference to play notification sound

Tags: android

I have a problem when notification comes that time two sounds are playing.

1)  system notification default sound

2)  user selected sound from ringtone preferences

I used this code to play notification sound in onReceive() method of BroadcastReceiver

```
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    String alarms = sharedPreferences.getString("ringtone",
            "default ringtone");

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(alarms);

    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);
    if (r != null)
        r.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the notification sound like this

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setSound(Uri.parse("notification_sound_path"));
```

Comment: after adding this code it's only playing system default sound not user selected sound from  ringtone preferences

Comment: In place of "notification_sound_path" you have to place the user selected sound from preferences...

Comment: still not working,      String soundPath = sharedPreferences.getString("ringtone",
    "default ringtone");

  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
    context);

  builder.setSound(Uri.parse(soundPath));

Comment: Is your default notification sound and user selected sound is different or not? Can you share your code how you setting the notification sound.

Comment: public class EditPreferences extends PreferenceActivity{
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
 } }  and my xml file <RingtonePreference
        android:defaultValue="defaultRingtone"
        android:key="ringtone"
        android:ringtoneType="notification"
        android:showDefault="true"
        android:showSilent="true"
        android:summary="Select a sound to play for a new notification message"
        android:title="Notification tone" />

Comment: Did you find a solution??? I've been searching for over an hour and still nothing.  Default sound plays no matter what